# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf using the #authentication utility

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using Spring Boot, the spring security starter and thymeleaf, I cannot access the #authentication utility after login (more precisely, it is null). I do not do any special configuration (assuming the starters will do that for me) and i do not include the sec: namespace in my templates (again, assuming I do not need it - all the examples I've seen so far don't need it either). 
I would like to call something like: `{#authentication.expression('isAuthenticated()')}`

For reference, here is the controller that gets called after authentication:

```
import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/site-admin")
public class VZSiteAdminController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mainScreen(Principal principal){

    return "site-admin";

    }
}
```

Comment: If you only have the starters you would still need to add a dependency on the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3` jar. That contains the class that registers the security integration with thymeleaf.

Comment: Did that... Still no success. Would I have to add it to my template?

Comment: Are you sure your loging is working correctly? And shouldn't the expression be something like `${#authentication}`, notice the `$`.

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to access a property from the principal object you should go like this:

```
<div th:text="${#authentication.principal.something}">
    The value of the "name" property of the authentication object should appear here.
</div>
```

This post was really helpful for me because I add to a user image that was stored in the principal object:

```
<img th:if="${#authentication.principal.image}"
    class="img-circle" th:src="${#authentication.principal.image}"
    width="100" height="100" alt="place-holder" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Spring boot thymeleaf starter doesn't contain it, you need to add thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3/4/5 as your dependency. 
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```